# 3D filled line plot

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix for contact positions and these positions are linear, therefore I can easily plot the contact positions within MATLAB and come out with the x amount of lines. At the moment I am plotting within a 2D graph.

```
for j= 1:5
    for k= 1:20
       Yijk(j,:,k)=x*tan_helix+one_array*(k-P)*Pb/P+one_array*(j-(L+1)/2)*Pb;
    end
end 

x_axis = linspace(0,b*1000, N+1);

figure;
for j=1:zPairs;
 hold on
 plot(x_axis,Yijk(j,:,k))
 hold off 
end
```

The above is only a small section of a large coding so all variables and parameters are stated else where.

Below is the graph this simply creates with a 2D graph:

[image]

What I wish to do is plot the correspoding contact to each of these positions, contact only occurs at positions > 0 and therefore will only occur along the lines plotted above. Therefore the plot will need to be in a 3D format and I am assuming that the lines will be plotted initially, then the contact_force and then a fill command as such - but I may be wrong.

What I am aiming to create is something similar to:

[image]

If any one has any guidance or tips it will be greatly appreciated as I am getting nowhere.

Please note the contact_force is also a matrix of the same dimensions as the contact positions.

---

```
 for j = 1:zPairs

    Xx = linspace(0,b*1000,N+1);
    Yy = Yijk(j,:,1);
    n = length(Xx);
    Zz = contact_force(j,:,1);

    Xp = zeros(2*n,1);
    Yp = zeros(2*n,1);

    Xp(1:N+1) = Xx;
    Xp(N+2:2*(N+1)) = Xx(N+1:-1:1);
    Yp(1:N+1) = Yy;
    Yp(N+2:2*(N+1)) = Yy(N+1:-1:1);
    Zp(1:N+1) = 0;
    Zp(N+2:2*(N+1)) = Zz(N+1:-1:1);

    figure(12);
      hold on
      patch(Xp,Yp,Zp,'c');
      title('Zone of Contact');
      hold off

 end
```

The above code works great, but only creates one graph as it is for (j,:,1). I would like to change this so as that it is for (j,:,k) and k number of graphs are created. How would I set up this for loop ?

Comment: "_The above is only a small section of a large coding so all variables and parameters are stated else where._" ... that way of presenting a question prevents potential helpers to know what your code is doing, what your variable look like (scalar, vector, matrices???) etc ... You would better create a small sample set which you can reproduce here, following the advices in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little MATLAB code to test it out. This program creates a polygon on top of a 2D line. `fill3` or `patch` functions are what you are looking for.

```
a = 2;
b = 1;

X = 0:10;
Y = a*X + b;
n = length(X);
Z = rand(n,1)*2+1;

Xp = zeros(2*n,1);
Yp = zeros(2*n,1);

Xp(1:n) = X;
Xp(n+1:2*n) = X(n:-1:1);
Yp(1:n) = Y;
Yp(n+1:2*n) = Y(n:-1:1);
Zp(1:n) = 0;
Zp(n+1:2*n) = Z(n:-1:1);

fill3(Xp,Yp,Zp,'c');
```

Comment: Tried this command (see edit) but unfortunately just received the contact lines in a 3d axis